# How to show/hide the textbox based on the selection made by dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html

I m new to jquery..I have a dropdown menu this different option.. When i select Others from the dropdown the text box as to be displayed.How can I do it.. Here is the code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
$("[name='select1']").on("change", function(){     //listen for change event on the select
    $(".otherprof").toggle(this.value==="other");  //toggle show/hide based on selected value
}).change();


html code
<select name="select1">
    <option value="doctor" id="doctor1">Doctor</option>
    <option value="nurse" id="nurse1">Nurse</option>
    <option value="other" id="other1">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="otherprof">
    <p>Please list your profession:
        <input type="text" name="otherproftext" id="otherproftext" maxlength="20">
    </p>
</div>
```

In this code the textbox is displayed it is not hide. Can u tel me whats the error in it..
Idea is that the textbox stays hidden until users click on "Other" in the dropdown, which in turn is supposed to display the textbox immediately.

Comment: Works wonderfully: http://jsfiddle.net/VFMug/ Just open your console to fix syntax error in your code... Or that just a typo in question..

Answer (score 0):

```
/// here is jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dallu7020/bbeu9/

```
// here i hav aassumed that you have select bo with selector id...
<select name="select1"  id="selector" >
   <option value="doctor" id="doctor1">Doctor</option>
   <option value="nurse" id="nurse1">Nurse</option>
   <option value="other" id="other1">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="otherprof">
    <p>Please list your profession:
        <input type="text" name="otherproftext" id="otherproftext" maxlength="20">
    </p>
</div>

// jquery

$('#selector').change(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == "other" )
    {
        $('.otherprof').slideDown();
    }
    else
    {
         $('.otherprof').slideUp();
    }
     });
```

Comment: you can do it with $("[name='select1']")

Comment: Oh i didn't saw you were using slide effect instead, i was thinking your answer was regarding selector. But anyway, won't resolve OP's issue